# Prove for Transitivity

Tags: solution-verification, relations

Let $A = \{1,2,3,4\}$ and let $f:\mathcal{P}(A) \to \mathbb{N}$ be the function defined by saying that $f(X)$ is the sum of the element of $X$, for each $X \in \mathcal{P}(A)$. (If $X = \emptyset$, then by convention we say that $f(X) = 0$.
Define relations $S,T$ on $\mathcal{P}(A)$ as follows:

$XSY$ if and only if $f(X)>f(Y)$ or $X = Y$

I have asked a similar question like this before about proving Reflexivity, but now I'm having trouble proving for **Transitivity**.

***My method:***

Transitive: if $xRy$ and $yRz$ then, $xRz$

Thus: $f(X)>f(Y)$ and $f(Y)>f(Z)$ then, $f(X)>f(Z)$

Therefore: S is transitive

---

So my question is, did I do this correctly? Because one of the comments was telling me to be careful about the transitive part.

Comment: But $XSY$ doesn't imply that $f(X)>f(Y)$. It is also possible that $X=Y$. So $XSY$ and $YSZ$ gives four cases: 1) $f(X)>f(Y) \land f(Y)>f(Z)$, 2) $f(X)>f(Y) \land Y=Z$, 3) $X=Y \land f(Y)=f(Z)$, 4) $X=Y \land Y=Z$.

Comment: @md2perpe The third case should be $X=Y \wedge f(Y) > f(Z)$.

Comment: @Georgios. Oops. That was a mistake. Thanks! Unfortunately it's too late to edit the comment.

Comment: @md2perpe ohh I see, thank you so much.